# SQL Handle special characters in strings during query SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database Customers. Columns as below

```
ID    CompanyName
1      Bon app'
2      %Benguir$
3      ABB?

DELETE FROM Customers WHERE CompanyName = 'Bon app\''
```

I wish to say delete records where CompanyName is `Bon app'` . Notice the `'` at the end.
I wish to do the same for `%Benguir$` and `ABB?`. Basically I want to know how to handle strings with special characters in SQL while using query

Comment: The only character you need to escape is a single quote, which you escape by doubling it. The rest just work.

Comment: All the other characters will be escaped on their own?

Comment: You can just give it a try you know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correct, you should only have issue with your first record with **Bon app'**. Please check from the below script how you can select all 3 records. This should help you to delete specific records.

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3fffd653b0d870597f2e5a64322083de)

```
WITH your_table(ID,CompanyName)
AS
(
    SELECT 1,'Bon app''' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'%Benguir$' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'ABB?'
)

SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE CompanyName = 'Bon app'''
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE CompanyName = '%Benguir$'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE CompanyName = 'ABB?'
```

I just demonstrate the selection for different Word. You can use above conditions and logic in your delete script.